# AVCaptureSession error -11819 when capturing video

Tags: ios, avfoundation

In my app I capture video through AVCaptureSession, using the callback:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

This works fine 95% of the time, but sometimes the preview layer freezes and I get the following error in my Xcode console:

```
AVCaptureSessionErrorKey = "Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11819 \"Cannot Complete Action\" UserInfo=0x170473bc0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Action, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try again later.}";
```

Any idea where this error might come from? This is on an iPhone 6+ running iOS 8.2

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this and the problem is the stopRunning method. This method is synchronous and blocks until the receiver has completely stopped running. The fix in my case was to call the method on a non-blocking thread. -11819 seems to be an indication of the method timing out.

Comment: But why does the problem occur when actually starting the capturing?

Answer (score 0):

please check  presentationTime
if (_writerAdaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {

```
        presentationTime = CMTimeMake(_writeCount * (1.0/60.0) * 1000, 1000);
        BOOL isSUc = [self.writerAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:cvBuffer withPresentationTime:presentationTime];
        if (isSUc == NO) {
            NSLog(@"appen error %@", self.videoWriter.error);
        }
        
        _writeCount++;
    }
```

please check
// *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '*** -[AVAssetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:] Cannot call method when status is 1'
// *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '*** -[AVAssetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:] Cannot call method when status is 4'

```
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            
            NSLog(@"_videoWriter.status 4 %ld", (long)weakSelf.videoWriter.status);
            [weakSelf.videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
                NSLog(@"finished ");

                NSLog(@"error %@", weakSelf.videoWriter.error);
//                self.assetWriter.error];
                weakSelf.videoWriter = nil;
            }];
        });
```